# Rails: Sorting Objects From Different Models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sorting

I've populated a hash with two different models. I then try to sort them like so:

```
@search_results = User.find(:all, :conditions => ['name LIKE ?', "%#{params[:query]}%"])
@search_results += Book.find(:all, :conditions => ['title LIKE ?', "%#{params[:query]}%"])
@search_results.sort! { |a,b| a.impressions_count <=> b.impressions_count }
```

This throws the following error:

```
comparison of User with Book failed
```

Both users and books have an integer-based impressions_count. Why can't I sort via this attribute? What other options do I have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I faced a similar problem recently and ended up writing some custom sql because all other ways returned an array. Pretty sure its not a good idea to use the sort method since it will always be more efficient to sort in SQL than ruby, especially when the data set gets large

```
  @combined_results = User.find_by_sql(["SELECT title, id, impressions_count, NULL as some_attribute_of_book
                                         FROM user
                                         WHERE title LIKE ?
                                         UNION SELECT title, id, impressions_count, some_attribute_of_book FROM book 
                                         WHERE title LIKE ?
                                         ORDER BY impressions_count", params[:query], params[:query]])
```

The above is completely untested code, more of an example than anything

Comment: After tinkering with this some, I almost have it working. (I hope.) The only problem is that its passing nil values. What might be causing this? I suspect it has something to do with "some_attribute_of_book," though I'm not sure what to put in its place.

Comment: some_attribute_of_book was just an example of how you could retrieve a field as NULL if it was not in the other model. Since you must have a field in both tables for a union to work. So if you dont need anything like that you can just remove it, otherwise replace with any field you want to pull back from the books table or vice versa. Hope that helps

Comment: I'm no longer getting nil results, but the hash is nevertheless empty. Even if I trim it down to this: User.find_by_sql(["SELECT name
                                         FROM users
                                         WHERE name LIKE ?", params[:query]])

Comment: Ah, now I see what's going on. Typically I can get the results by passing in just a portion of the query, such as "ook" returning "The Book of the Dead" and "George Book." Now I have enter the full search query for it work. I'm not sure why this is happening, as I'm still using LIKE. I'll look into this and let you know what I find.

Comment: Got it. I needed to replace params[:query] with "%#{params[:query]}%". Anyway, it's now working great. Thanks for your help, Jon!

Comment: Okay, there's actually a pretty big problem with this approach. It converts the Book class objects into User class objects. Any idea how to work around that? I'll keep looking into this and update you if I find a solution.

Comment: Yeah this is one of the draw backs of this approach, you can add a column via migration to your book model (if you go for this method dont name it type as that is reserved for table inheritance) perhaps is_book. This way you can determine if it is a book or not. Its a bit of a hassle but as far as I know it is the only way to retrieve combined results as an activerecord object which obviously gives much more flexibility

Comment: I've got an attribute in the Books model that can't contain the @ symbol, while the Users model has an email attribute that requires it. I just threw those attributes into the mix and checked for the @ symbol. It's a bit hacky, but at least it works. Thanks again, Jon!